# How to display a message based on time

Tags: java, android

I need to display a message in android based on time. The coding of mine is below:

```
package com.example.lenovo.timegreetfriends;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button greetButton;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            greetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greetButton);

            greetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMessage);

            //get a reference to the EditText so that we can read in the value typed by the user
            EditText editFriendName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFriendName);
            Date date = new Date();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int min = date.getMinutes();
            String friendName = editFriendName.getText().toString();

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.greetButton:
                    if(hours>=1 || hours<=12) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if(hours>=12 || hours<=16) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if(hours>=16 || hours<=21) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if(hours>=21 || hours<=24) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    textMessage.setText("Good Day "+friendName+"!");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
```

- **Case:1** If the user types a text (say john) and press a button at 9am.

  - **Output:** `Good morning john`
- **Case 2:** If the user types a text (say hari) and press button at 3pm

  - **Output:** `Good evening Hari. I dont get like that.`

Comment: I've removed the links you had to a YouTube video. Having multiple copies of the same link made it appear to be spam. I never watched the video, so I don't know if it was appropriate, or not, for there to be one copy (at most). However, having multiple copies of the link was not appropriate. Keep in mind that if it's that questions *must* be self contained. If there's information in the video that's needed to be able to answer this question, then you *must* reduce it to text (or an image, if needed) and include it directly in your question.

Comment: To make the question easier i just shared the youtube link. I believe there is lot of difference between reading a book and watching a video.If i elaborate this question without video people take much time in reading. that's why i shared the youtube link. If you viewed the video and then if you removed it. There is no issue. Without viewing 4min video of clear explanation of my question and removing is like having books related to peace and saying these books are preaching violence

Comment: Fariz Starc, As I said: I removed it because having 3 links to it makes it look like spam and is excessive. In addition, questions **must** be self-contained (i.e. *all* the information needed to identify the problem has to be in the question). This is the case, because then when something that's external to the question goes away (link rot, removed, etc.) the question becomes useless. The goal of Stack Overflow isn't to answer *your* question. It's to have questions that are useful to future visitors, which means they must remain actual questions over time (i.e. not depend on external links).

Comment: At first when i inserted the link. i didn't find it click able so i added one more. as a moderator you can remove the extra link for sure and  make one link in the screen but you removed all the link. That link is a 4min video of my question in which the question is explained very clearly. By using just text it takes a lot of page scroller to view the question and if i want to use pictures i need to add 10 pictures to make the question understandable in order to avoid all difficulties i posted the link. This question is not a single individual question its assignment for young users

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||` as for all conditions

```
hours>=1 && hours<=12
```

otherwise `16` >= `1` so first case will be executed and control won't go further

`||` : mean OR condition , required any one condition as `true` to proceed

`&&` : mean AND condition , required every condition as `true` to proceed

and also define the upper and lower bounds properly as

```
 if(hours>=1 && hours<=12) {} 
 else if(hours>12 && hours<=16) {} 
 //          ^^^
```

and as @Dileep Patel mention use appropriate variables containing values as `hour` instead of `hours` though it's wired that there is no `hours` variable defined

Comment: I tried that it doesn't worked out.  Anyway thanks for your timely help

Comment: @FarizStarc change the range of condition as well like if( ... <=12) then else if(... >12

Comment: ok. i make the change  can you pls tell me how to add minutes in it.

Comment: @FarizStarc you can also get the minutes from same calendar instance as `Calendar.MINUTE` and combine it with `if` using `&&` , try it for learning purpose

Comment: thanks. actually i need if like if 9:00am to 11:59am else if 12:00pm to 3:59pm i hope it will be useful. i try out

Comment: @FarizStarc hint :`(hours>=1 && hours<=11 && minutes <=59)`

Comment: @FarizStarc i am glad that i could help , happy coding